# Javascript ,one object with callback handler, how to rewrite it into await/async style?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I was using an api, it’s object provide callback handler,a search function.it looks like this:

```
function searchAndDoSomething(name){
    let searchObj = new APIobj(para1,{onSearchComplete:searchCompleteHandler});
    searchObj.search(name);
}
function searchCompleteHandler(result){
    doSomething(result);
}
```

My goal is to make it like this:

```
Async Main(){
      result = await searchAndDoSomething(name);
      searchCompleteHandler(result);  
}
```

But how to rewrite searchAndDoSomething?

```
async searchAndDoSomething(name){
     return new Promise(function(resolve){
         let searchObj = new APIobj(para1,{onSearchComplete:resolve};//this will call a resolve function.
     //and
     resolve(name);//instead of searchObj.search will no effect too.
    })
}
```

Comment: Is there no way for `APIobj` to signal failure?

Comment: I look up the instructions,seem the search kresult object have no

Comment: I think your comment got cut off there...

Comment: I look up the instructions,seem the search ‘result’ object have no failed type, maybe I don’t know the failure stayment. So I block my WiFi,and see console pops up an GET error. End with 0().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attempt is close, but since you need to create a promise explicitly (since `APIobj` doesn't), there's no reason for your function to be `async`. Also, you only want to call `resolve` once:

```
searchAndDoSomething(name) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const searchObj = new APIobj(para1, {onSearchComplete: resolve});
        searchObj.search(name);
    });
}
```

Presumably there's a way for `APIobj` to signal failure; if so, you wan to call `reject`. For instance, if I guess at a callback called `onSearchError`:

```
searchAndDoSomething(name) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const searchObj = new APIobj(para1, {
            onSearchComplete: resolve,
            onSearchError: reject
        });
        searchObj.search(name);
    });
}
```

You can then use that like this:

```
async Main() { // Note it's `async`, not `Async`
    const result = await searchAndDoSomething(name); // note declaration
    searchCompleteHandler(result);  
}
```

or

```
async Main() {
    searchCompleteHandler(await searchAndDoSomething(name));  
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, keen eye as ever!